# I just want to use old password and new password without sending reset link to email in app to change password by using firebase in swift2

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-authentication

*In android, I use reauthenticate but in swift, which way can I use? For example, in android like this*

```
Firebase.getCurrentUser().reauthenticate(EmailAuthProvider.
                                    getCredential(Firebase.getCurrentUser().getEmail(),old_pass))
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                           //add some code
                                        }
                                    })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                   //add some code
                                }
                            });
                        }});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Firebase documentation, this should work:

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
var credential: FIRAuthCredential

let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
var credential: FIRAuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

Here's my source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user